# 7" LCD Display not working with Android Things

Tags: pi-3, display, android-things

I'm new to the Raspberry Pi community, but I want to work with the Pi 3 and Android Things.

I want to connect a 7" display via HDMI and USB to my Raspberry Pi 3 (running with Android Things 0.5.1)
Here the link to display: [7" HDMI LCD (C)](http://www.waveshare.com/product/mini-pc/raspberry-pi/7inch-hdmi-lcd-c.htm)

I also followed the instruction on the manual and added the lines to the `config.txt` which is located in the root of my SD card

```
max_usb_current=1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=1
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 1024 600 60 6 0 0 0
hdmi_drive=1
```

Then I plug in the display. It's definitely on! But the display only shows a black screen.

#### My config.txt

I attached my complete `config.txt`, maybe I'm missing something. And again: I only added the lines shown above

```
kernel=u-boot-dtok.bin
framebuffer_depth=16

# Prevent the firmware from loading HAT overlays now that we handle pin muxing.
# ourselves. See:
# https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/device-tree.md#part3.4
dtoverlay=

dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtparam=spi=on
dtparam=audio=on

# pwm and I2S are mutually-exclusive since they share hardware clocks.
dtoverlay=pwm-2chan-with-clk,pin=18,func=2,pin2=13,func2=4
dtoverlay=generic-i2s

start_x=1

# Tell U-boot to always use the "serial0" interface for the console, which is
# set to whichever uart (uart0 or uart1) is set to the header pins. This doesn't
# interfere with the uart selected for Bluetooth.
dtoverlay=chosen-serial0

# Enable skip-init on the UART interfaces, so U-Boot doesn't attempt to
# re-initialize them.
dtoverlay=rpi-uart-skip-init

# Add pin devices to the system for use by the runtime pin configuration driver.
dtoverlay=runtimepinconfig
dtoverlay=uart1
dtoverlay=bcm2710-rpi-3-b-spi0-pin-reorder

# Tell the I2S driver to use the cprman clock.
dtoverlay=bcm2710-rpi-3-b-i2s-use-cprman

# Uncomment to disable serial port on headers, use GPIO14 and GPIO15
# as gpios and to allow the core_freq to change at runtime.
enable_uart=1
core_freq=400

# Enable hardware graphics acceleration.
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d,cma-256
mask_gpu_interrupt0=0x400
avoid_warnings=2

# Support official RPi display.
dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds3231
dtoverlay=rpi-ft5406
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_drive=2

# Support custom Waveshare 7inch display
max_usb_current=1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 1024 600 60 6 0 0 0
hdmi_drive=1
```

#### Contacted the support

I also contacted the manufacturer support, and I received this:

> Yes, it can.  However, during the test. With only long HDMI cable such
>   as 1m the LCD could display with new version android things. We don't
>   find the reason.

### Update - Downgrade to Android Things 0.4.1

I created a new image with Android Thing 0.4.1 and extended the `config.txt`with my device specs, and voilá it's working...

But can maybe someone here help me out to get the display running und 0.5.1? Here is my "updated" `config.txt`

There are some differences between this config and the one I posted above. And of course this config isn't runnable for AT 0.5.1

```
kernel=u-boot-dtok.bin
framebuffer_depth=16
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtparam=spi=on
dtparam=audio=on

# pwm and I2S are mutually-exclusive since they share hardware clocks.  To
# enable I2S comment out the pwm line and uncomment the generic-i2s line.
dtoverlay=pwm-2chan-with-clk,pin=18,func=2,pin2=13,func2=4
# dtoverlay=generic-i2s

start_x=1

# Tell U-boot to always use the "serial0" interface for the console, which is
# set to whichever uart (uart0 or uart1) is set to the header pins. This doesn't
# interfere with the uart selected for Bluetooth.
dtoverlay=chosen-serial0

# Enable skip-init on the UART interfaces, so U-Boot doesn't attempt to
# re-initialize them.
dtoverlay=rpi-uart-skip-init

# Uncomment to disable serial port on headers, use GPIO14 and GPIO15
# as gpios and to allow the core_freq to change at runtime.
enable_uart=1
core_freq=400

max_usb_current=1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=1
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 1024 600 60 6 0 0 0
hdmi_drive=1
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the [SC7B](https://www.waveshare.com/7inch-hdmi-lcd-b.htm) variant of this display (800x480) working with Android Things 0.5.1-dp.

To do this I used the configuration supplied in the documentation (similar to yours) and commented out the RPi official display entries at the end of the file. I also removed the extra `hdmi_mode=1` line as it looks like a duplicate line. Here is the changed lines of the configuration I used:

```
# Support official RPi display.
#dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds3231
#dtoverlay=rpi-ft5406
#hdmi_force_hotplug=1
#hdmi_drive=2

# SC7B display
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
max_usb_current=1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 800 480 60 6 0 0 0
```

I did also have to follow the manufacturer suggestion to use a longer cable - the supplied short cable does not work and results in a blank display.

Comment: And the 7B is, seven beers? Please add references, data and relevant info.